# ggplot2 grouping data by the first word of the row name and assigning a color pallet to each group

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, group-by

I have the following dataframe, cafe:

```
cafe_type   X   Y
bread - white   354 1
bread - wheat   674 3
bread - rye 756 4
bread - sourdough   234 2
milk - cow  454 6
milk - soy  345 7
milk - almond   323 8
bagel - white   234 3
bagel - everything  453 4
bagel - wheat   556 6
bagel - egg 678 9
```

I graphed this data using:

```
ggplot(cafe, aes(X,Y)) + geom_point()
```

I want to group the data by the first word in the row name (i.e. bread), and then chose a different color palette for each group (i.e. each bread dot is a different shade of orange, each milk dot is a different shade of blue, and each bagel is a different shade of green). I have been running into errors with the group_by function and I am not sure how to proceed. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Jessie

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would adress is putting your food items as an actual column in your data.frame.

```
cafe$item <- factor(rownames(cafe), levels = unique(rownames(cafe)))
```

Next, you would want to build the plot. Add the item in the `aes()` as colour.

```
ggplot(df, aes(X, Y, colour = item)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_manual(
    breaks = levels(cafe$item),
    limits = levels(cafe$item),
    values = c("orange", "darkorange", "orange2", "darkorange2",
               "dodgerblue", "blue", "deepskyblue",
               "limegreen","forestgreen","green","lawngreen")
  )
```

Now the tricky bit is getting the order of the food items correct, which is done through `breaks` and `limits` inside `scale_colour_manual()`. A bit of work is to pick and choose colours for your food items that you like, but you're free to experiment with the colours. This is what the plot looked like for me:

[image]

I don't know where the errors in your `group_by()` came from, but I don't think you would need it to produce the plot. Good luck!